# SSH Password Authentication failing

Tags: ssh

I get this error if I've been closing and restarting my SSH sessions in a short window of time and goes away after awhile. I'm sure my password is correct. Each of my two client's response to the error doesn't give me a lot to go on for search engine troubleshooting.

Under mRemote on Windows 7, outside the main window a 2nd window is drawn which disappears immediately. The shell I opened (in a tab) will display only **Using username "Bob".** for a second or two before closing without notice.

Connectbot on Android is more specific. It connects to host and verifies. After the password prompt it tells me **Authentication method 'password' failed.**

What is happening here?

Comment: What does the server's logs say? Run `sshd -rdd` for diagnostic messages.

Comment: @grawity https://gist.github.com/839208
Was transcriped and checked for errors but might have small errors or transpositions due LD

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom. In my case, the problem was as silly as having entered an extra space at the end of the user name on connectbot's configuration

My server's log (Ubuntu server) would display the error:

```
> tail -f /var/log/auth.log
...
Jan  5 00:27:03 wimel sshd[21366]: Invalid user coderazzi  from 62.143.154.115
```

This line was displayed as soon as I would try to connect: password was never used, in fact.